# I have to find the surface area of a paraboloid within a cylinder.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area

I have to find the surface area of a paraboloid within a cylinder.

The paraboloid is $x = y^2 + z^2$ and the cylinder is $y^2 + z^2 = 4$, and I know the equation but I have no idea how to set this problem up, can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(y,z)= y^2 + z^2.$   As I understand your question, you are to find the surface area for the cylindrical region $y^2+z^2\leq 4.$    Then 
$$
A = \int\int_{y^2+z^2\leq 4}  \sqrt{1 + (g_y)^2 + (g_z)^2} \ dy \, dz.
$$
Then convert to polar coordinates: 
$$
A = \int^{2\pi}_0 \int^2_0 \sqrt{1 + 4r^2} \ r  \, dr \ d\theta
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking he might want us to convert the problem but I was really confused because we usually are given most of the information. But thanks again.